# Clue game in Prolog

Tags: prolog

So I am supposed to recreate a small implementation of the game clue.

I am given a set of facts, and must output a list of possible suspects found by Prolog. Given a single fact for a "unique" suspect, The program should then only output the unique suspect found.

I have all of the logic done, now I am just having a hard time figuring out how to stop the program from finding suspects when I give it the "unique" suspect fact.

Could I get a little help from another eye to see where i am going wrong with this, my beginner proficiency has baffled me on how to get this to stop or organize the cuts in order to get it to stop.

Here is the code:

```
%% Facts

rich(mrBoddy).
affair_with(msGreen, mrBoddy).
affair_with(missScarlet, mrBoddy).
married_to(profPlum, msGreen).
greedy(colMustard).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Rules

affair(X, Y) :- affair_with(X, Y).
affair(X, Y) :- affair_with(Y, X), !.

married(X, Y) :- married_to(X, Y).
married(X, Y) :- married_to(Y, X), !.

greed(X, Victim) :-
    greedy(X),
    not(rich(X)),
    rich(Victim).

hate(X, Victim) :- 
    married(X, Someone),
    affair(Someone, Victim).

murder(X, Victim) :-
    hate(X, Victim);
    greed(X, Victim).

%%% THIS IS THE UNIQUE SUSPECT FACT--- suspect_found(profPlum).
suspect_found(X) :-
    X = profPlum;
    X = missScarlet;
    X = msGreen;
    X = colMustard.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%       
%% Solution

suspect(Killer, mrBoddy) :-
    murder(Killer, mrBoddy),
    suspect_found(Killer).
```

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that the `suspect_found/1` predicate has multiple solutions (because of the use of semicolons `;` in its body) and that it does not use any of the other predicates (rules and facts) in your program. Therefore it is only natural the first answer from it is `profPlum` and by backtracking it also
yields `missScarlet`, `msGreen` and `colMustard`.

Comment: it actually doesn't yield missScarlet and msGreen. It finds that the suspects are profPlum and colMustard just fine based off of my logic. What I am trying to get this to do now is just display the unique suspect when I uncomment the suspect_found/1 fact. That is my only issue

Comment: (cont.) I only described the behaviour of `suspect_found/1` as given by the uncommented clause, not  what `suspect/1` yields. Uncommenting the previous clause, `suspect_found/1` yields all the names, repeating `profPlum`, and  `suspect/1` gives  `profPlum` twice and `colMustard`. Keeping only the 1st clause `suspect/1` gives `profPlum` once. To get only the first answer even if there are more, either do not use backtracking on `suspect/1` or add a cut at the end of its clause. As it is the `suspect_found/1` predicate only accepts some answers filtering out the others. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Ok, using a cut, it does only yield profPlum. But if I do not uncomment that code then I should still get back profPlum and colMustard. I am completely lost on how to have both behaviors instead of one or the other

Comment: You may have one predicate for each behaviour, but never a predicate with more than one behaviour. Or do you want to find all the possible combinations of possible suspects? If yes, then find the list of all suspects and then write a predicate that finds all the possible combinations of members of that list.

Comment: Yes I would like to find all the possible suspects. I would only need to do this when the unique suspect fact is commented out. In the case it is uncommented, I should only get back the unique suspect.

Would you mind elaborating just a tiny bit, with a sample code. That would be very helpful. I'm not asking for a real answer. Just a good step in the right direction that will show me what is really going wrong with my code. Prolog is difficult to get a hang of...

Comment: Ok, then rename your unique suspect fact to, say, `unique_suspect` and add a 1st clause to `suspect` similar to the 2nd one but using `unique_suspect` instead of  `suspect_found` and having a cut after it. If you do not understand how this works you should ask for help.

Comment: I do understand how this works. I think my point is not getting across. I cannot just rename that fact to unique_suspect. This is because, that fact must be commented out. That would mean using it in my suspect clause will cause an exception for an undefined predicate. When the fact is commented out, I MUST get multiple possible suspects. Then the fact must be uncommented to show only one. That is the big issue I am having. I cannot just create it as it's own fact. It must have another predicate with the same name to backtrack on in order to not cause an exception when run.

Comment: You get the exception because your Prolog is either too strict or is configured to throw it to help debugging. You can avoid it and still use `unique_suspect` by adding a 1st clause `unique_suspect(_) :- !, fail.` that makes the predicate fail. You then keep the other clause uncommented and if you want it to be used just comment out the 1st one. This follows what you asked for, but un/commenting out clauses like this is not good practice.